# use compile api to parse ts interface,but the symbol is always undefined

Tags: typescript

my code is just like this, i use command "ts-node main.ts" to run this ts file and try to log the symbol of the interface, but always got undefined

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';

const fileName = 'test.ts'

const source = `
export interface Company {
name: string;
address: Address;
}

export interface Employee {
name: string;
age: number;
company: Company;
}
`;

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(fileName, sourceCode, ts.ScriptTarget.ES2020, true);

const program = ts.createProgram(\[fileName\], {});

for (const statement of sourceFile.statements) {
  if (ts.isInterfaceDeclaration(statement)) {
    const symbol = checker.getSymbolAtLocation(statement.name);
    console.log('symbol: '+symbol)
    const type = checker.getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol(symbol);
  }
}
```

my typescript version is v5.0.4 and ts-node version is v10.9.1

i expected the really symbol of the interface

Comment: Where checker is declared or defined ?

Comment: Typo `source` or `sourceCode`?